# SSRS OLEDB CSV source not working unless share has full control to Everyone. Excel works on a share with Read Only access though

Tags: csv, oledb, ssrs-2012, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I have a report that uses a CSV file as a datasource. In Visual Studio, I can point it at the file on a share and it works. When I deploy it to the SSRS server though, it brings back an error:

`The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file 'forecast.csv'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.`

Putting the file onto a share which has Everyone granted Full Control, it works. This is obviously not an acceptable security situation. I am using the following OLEDB connection string:

`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="\\server\share\Apps\Folder1\Folder2\DEV\SSRS\Report Foo";Mode=Read;Extended Properties="text;HDR=YES;FMT=CSVDelimited"`

Of interest, another report that uses an xls file as data source works on a share that does not have Everyone Full Control access. I initially thought that it was a DFS issue but it is actually that the share needs Everyone to have Full Control. Setting the share to Full Control for the user doesn't work, it has to be Everyone

I have logged this as a bug with [Microsoft](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37497949-ssrs-oledb-csv-source-not-working-unless-share-has)

Comment: I've now tried to use a system DSN using the `Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)` driver but similar issue

Comment: Further desperation - I've tried using a symbolic link to the files and also the directory. Same error...

Comment: Have tried on different servers on 2014 and 2017 SSRS as well BTW, same thing.